# Vuejs emit event when datas are rendered

Tags: events, scroll, vue.js, components

In vuejs, I'm developing a conversation chat between two users. I have nested component like this

```
Chat
    ->ChatLog
        -> ChatMessage
    ->ChatComposer
```

The chat component has the structure of the chat (a panel in bootstrap) and also that's where I retrieve with Axios, when the page is loaded, all the messages from the database.

```
axios
.get('/conversation/'+this.conversation.id+'/message')
.then((response) => {
    this.messages = response.data;
    this.manageHeightChat();
    this.scrollToEnd();
});
```

And when the I get all the message, I dispatch them to the `ChatLog` component

```
<chat-message v-for="message in messages" v-bind:message="message" v-bind:user="user"></chat-message>
```

which dispatch each message to the `ChatMessage` component.

So when the callback method is called with all the messages, they are dispatched to the other components and then the two methods `manageHeightChat` and `scrollToEnd` are called.

```
scrollToEnd() {
    var container = this.$refs.chatlog;
    container.scrollTop = container.scrollHeight;
    console.log(container.scrollHeight);
}
```

The problem is that the last method (`scrollToEnd`) is called before the messages are rendered by the `ChatLog` and `ChatMessage` so the `container.scrollHeight` is not the good size.

To verify it I added something like :

```
setTimeout(function () {
    this.scrollToEnd();
}.bind(this), 1000);
```

And everything was working fine.

So how and where would you put some event to tell chat that the content is rendered and that I can call the `scrollToEnd` method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [nextTick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick). When you set the message data, you need to wait for Vue to update the DOM. That is what `nextTick` is for. Use it pretty much like you're using `setTimeout`

```
axios
.get('/conversation/'+this.conversation.id+'/message')
.then((response) => {
    this.messages = response.data;
    this.manageHeightChat();
    this.$nextTick(this.scrollToEnd.bind(this));
});
```

Comment: Thanks ! that's exactly it ! :)